# Can GitHub Actions create a release to a public repo from a private repo?

Tags: github-actions

I want to create a release that contains assets for users to download. Since it is a private repo, I want to create the release in a separate public repo. Is this doable in GitHub Actions?

There are `owner` and `repo` parameters in [create-release](https://github.com/actions/create-release) action, but I kept getting errors after setting them to a different repo:

```
   - name: Create Release
     id: create_release
     uses: actions/create-release@v1
     env:
       GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }} # A personal access token
     with:
       tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
       release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
       draft: false
       prerelease: false
       owner: foo
       repo: another_public_repo
```

> Error: Validation Failed:
> {"resource":"Release","code":"custom","field":"tag_name","message":"tag_name
> is not a valid tag"},
> {"resource":"Release","code":"custom","message":"Published releases
> must have a valid tag"},
> {"resource":"Release","code":"invalid","field":"target_commitish"}

Comment: Error `tag_name is not a valid tag`. That means in the public repo in which you are creating the release you need to create that tag first.

Comment: Do u know how to create it in a github action? We need to create one in the public repo from the private repo action.

Comment: On which event is your workflow triggered?

Comment: on:
  # Trigger the workflow on the new 'v*' tag created
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*"

Comment: Check out my answer, it should work then. And please edit your question to include the trigger code.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to specify an existing tag in `tag_name`. In your case that means creating the tag in the public repository before creating the release. Or you can specify a branch or commit SHA in `commitish`, which is used if the tag specified in `tag_name` doesn't exist.

```
  - name: Checkout public repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: foo/another_public_repo
      path: another_public_repo
  - name: Get tag name from ref
    shell: bash
    run: echo "::set-output name=tag::${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}"
    id: get_tag
  - name: Create tag in public repository
    run: |
      cd ${{github.workspace}}/another_public_repo
      git tag ${{ steps.get_tag.outputs.tag }}
      git push --tags --porcelain
  - name: Create Release
    id: create_release
    uses: actions/create-release@v1
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }} # A personal access token
    with:
      tag_name: ${{ steps.get_tag.outputs.tag }}
      release_name: Release ${{ steps.get_tag.outputs.tag }}
      draft: false
      prerelease: false
      owner: foo
      repo: another_public_repo
```